# The setHour Function changing the timezone for a function

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, timezone, nsdate

So I am trying to get the current date and time and then trying to override the Hours and the minutes so as to set up a fire time. But whenever I use the [comp sethour] functionality it reverts it to GMT timings for some reason.

In the header file I have :

```
static int re_hour = 19;
static int re_minute = 52;
```

and in the .m File I have this function

```
- (void) ScheduleTimer {

    NSCalendar* myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    //Get The GMT Time
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

    //Get The Current Timezone and then convert the Time
    NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* nowTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:now];
    NSInteger nowGMTOffset = [nowTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:now];
    NSTimeInterval interval = nowGMTOffset - currentGMTOffset;
    NSDate* nowDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:now];

   //Setting the restart Time
   NSDateComponents *comp = [myCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit|NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:nowDate];

   [comp setHour:re_hour];
   [comp setMinute:re_minute];

   NSDate *restartTime = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:comp];
   NSLog(@"The time of restart :%@",restartTime);
}
```

and it always seems to return:

```
 2014-08-26 19:52:34.032 SASMobile[2605:60b] The time of restart :2014-08-27 02:52:34 +0000
```

Comment: when you NSLog date it will always print GMT date. what is your issue.put your cursor on restartTime it will show you your local date. but if you log it will show you GMT.

Comment: Oh thanks, did not know that, Though I do find this weird.